# How can I show notification which will be removed after some time?

Tags: android, notifications

I need to show a lot of notifications to StatusBar. But in order to not to fill up statusbar with my messages I have to automatically remove notification after 1 minute, for example. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Create  `notification` and create `Alarm` for required duration
2. Cancel the notification using `NotificationManager.cancel(id)` in `BroadcastRecevier` of `Alarm`

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Timer:

```
    Notification notification = nb.build();

    notifManager.notify(id, notification);

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifManager.cancel(id);
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, REMOVE_TIME, 1000);
```